# Finitely spaned subspaces of topological vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a proper finite dimensional subspace of a TVS (with infinite dimension). I have already shown that $F$ will be closed. It looks like $F$ must have an empty interior (possibly subject to some constraints on the underlying field).

Could anyone give me a tip?

Comment: If the TVS is finite-dimensional, then the whole space is a finite-dimensional subspace with non-empty interior. I *think* that any proper subspace will have non-empty interior, regardless of finite-dimensionality, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. These seems so obvious, and it looks like it will be "choose $y$ l.i. of the generators of. Then..."

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, "any proper subspace will have empty interior".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the underlying field $k$ is endowed with the discrete topology, the TVS $X$ may also be endowed with the discrete topology, and all subsets are open, including finite  dimensional subspaces.

Conversely, if $0$ is not an isolated point of $k$, and $U$ is a non-empty open set contained in a proper subspace $Y\subsetneq X$, then pick $u\in U$ and we obtain an open set $U-u$ by translating $U$.

Pick any $v\notin Y$ so we have a continuous map $f\colon k\to X$ given by: $$f\colon \lambda \mapsto \lambda v.$$

Then $f^{-1}(U-u)=\{0\}$ is open, contradicting $0$ not being isolated.

Comment: This Answer is useful in pointing out the holes in the problem statement given in the Question.  The other Answer "glibly" assumes the field is real numbers, which is reasonable in the context of topological vector spaces, but bears careful articulation.

Comment: @hardmath Excuse me for assuming that the underlying field is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe one could say that this is reasonable, since every functional analysis class in the world is taught over those fields. "glibly"? I just wanted to make this sound less terrifying, as OP starts the question as "I'm feeling way dumb". I agree, this is a better answer than mine, but no reason to be ironic about the way I choose to communicate judging by how OP chooses to put it.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: I'm sorry if my remark seemed overly critical.  The two Answers work together to set out the circumstances that were not set up well in the Question.  If you add a brief assumption to your post about using a real (or complex?) field, I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: @hardmath I have added the assumption

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments: Suppose that $X$ is a topological vector space and that $Y\subset X$ is a proper subspace, regardless of dimension. Then $Y$ has empty interior.

EDIT: All this post is valid under the assumption that our underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ endowed with their usual topology.

Proof: Suppose on the contrary that $Y$ has an interior point, say $y\in Y$. Then we may find an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $V\subset Y$. Since $Y$ is proper, we have an element $x\in X\setminus Y$.

Consider the directed set $(0,1)$ directed under $\alpha\prec \alpha'$ if and only if $\alpha'<\alpha$ (so when im taking the limit as $\alpha\in(0,1)$ i am actually letting $\alpha$ approach $0$). Now consider the net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in(0,1)}$ given by $x_\alpha=(1-\alpha)y+\alpha x$. Note that $$\lim_{\alpha\in(0,1)}x_\alpha-y=\lim_{\alpha\in(0,1)}\alpha(x-y)=0$$
because $\alpha$ becomes very small and $X$ is a topological vector space, so scaling is continuous. Thus $x_\alpha\to y$, so we may find $\alpha_o\in(0,1)$ such that $x_{\alpha_o}\in V$, i.e. $(1-\alpha_o)y+\alpha_ox\in V$. But $V\subset Y$, so $(1-\alpha_o)y+\alpha_ox\in Y$. Now $Y$ is a subspace and $y\in Y$, so $(1-\alpha_o)y\in Y$, so $(1-\alpha_o)y+\alpha_ox-(1-\alpha_o)y\in Y$, i.e. $\alpha_ox\in Y$, i.e. $x\in Y$, a contradiction.

A comment: don't feel dumb.

<s>How to come up with this proof yourself:</s>

1. Think about how to prove this in a normed space.
2. draw a picture.
3. Now throw the norm in the trashcan and translate everything in topological language.
4. Say out loud "that's all folks!"